# How expensive is select distinct * query

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql, sql-server-2012

In sql server 2012, I have got a table with more than 25 million rows with duplicates.  The table doesn't have unique index.  It only has a non-clustered index.  I wanted to eliminate duplicates and so, I m thinking of the below

```
select distinct * into #temp_table from primary_table
truncate primary_table
select * into primary_table from #temp_table
```

I wanted to know how expensive is select distinct * query.  If my procedure above is very expensive, I wanted to know if there is another alternate way.

Comment: That looks a very painful way of clearing duplicates, not to mention what happens to the users when your truncate has cleared all the data out. [Here are some ideas](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3317433/314291) on how to delete duplicates more delicately - the accepted answer doesn't require a unique or primary key.

Comment: Thats correct Stuart.  Very painful.  Thanks for the ideas.  I would also like to know how sql-server manages to give unique rows (like does it uses something like a hash).

Comment: Do a google for `sql uniquifier` - e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12321905/why-does-sql-server-add-a-4-byte-integer-to-non-unique-clustered-indexes). Rows are still unique to SqlServer :)

Comment: Don't forget that, after you've done this, put something in place (e.g. a primary key or unique key) to stop this happening again. Or do you want to have to perform this clean up more than once?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how expensive it is, but an alternate way is to create another table with a primary key, insert all the data there and silently reject the duplicates as stated here

http://web.archive.org/web/20180404165346/http://sqlblog.com:80/blogs/paul_white/archive/2013/02/01/a-creative-use-of-ignore-dup-key.aspx

basically, using IGNORE_DUP_KEY